# MacOS - UIKit/UIKit.h not found

Tags: objective-c, macos, uiview, uikit

Try to

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

And get error:

> UIKit/UIKit.h file not found

What is it and how fix it ?))) Try to import Foundation - all ok )

Comment: Since you tagged this "macos", I suppose you are doing this in a macOS app? Well, UIKit isn't available on macOS. UIKit is an iOS thing. Also, why did you tag this "swift"? How is this related to Swift at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally for macOS you could only use `AppKit` as an UI framwork, which is quite different from `UIKit`, so you couldn't reuse iOS code for macOS.

So you have to learn a much different framerwork with `NSView` base view instead of `UIView` and a lot of differences.

But then apple supported porting iOS apps to macOS. To do this you need to create an iOS app(if you don't have one) and turn on that option in the settings. Check out more at [Running Your iOS Apps on macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/running-your-ios-apps-on-macos)

You would still need to do a lot a work in making your app for macOS comfortable for users, but if you have no background in `AppKit`, probably it's still easier to go for `UIKit`

Comment: Thanks much! Yeap, i already try to work with NS...